# Play video inside PDF on iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf, video

Is it possible to play video inside a PDF?

Thanks

Comment: acutally pdf is working but how to add those xtra effect like zoom in n out

Comment: From my experience i used like a markup to operate audio or video on the pdf.

Comment: Embed it in a UIScrollView?  Or is that not what you're asking.